# Mongodb find where exists in other collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a `user` collection and a `document` one, where entries have a `owner` field that is a reference to the user `ObjectId(_id)`.

I'm amazed I can't find all users that have at least a document...

I tried:

```
db.getCollection('user').find({_id: {
  $in: db.getCollection('document').find({}).map(function(f) {return f.owner}).distinct()
}});
```

but it won't work and anyway it really feels like not the correct way to do this since all `document`s need to be loaded in memory.

I tried to use http://www.querymongo.com but it really did not help.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: remove the distinct(). No direct method available for remove duplicate values of array in mongo-cli